# GWT: retrieve Components from FormPanel/VerticalPanel which are added dynamically

Tags: gwt, components, custom-component, smartgit

I am creating a web page using GWT 2.5.0, in this I used lots of composite component. And the web page is developed based on XML .

So here we parse the XML and according to each element add componnet to a  VerticalPanel and finally add it to a FormPanel and then return it to add to RootPanel. Beside the Component corresponds to XML I add a Button, call it submit button, **on its click event I want to get the values of every component in that form**. 
To clear what my idea is , below is the pseudo code of my work:

```
public FormPanel createFormWithComponents(){

    FormPanel fp = new FormPanel();
    vp = new VerticalPanel();
    //these are creatred based on the xml
    ABC coutn = new ABC (null,"pressure count",true);
    PI propotion =  new PI(12.5,"HR percentage");

    vp.add(coutn);
    vp.add(propotion);
    //a common button to every form created here
    Button submit = new Button("submit");
    vp.add(submit);
    submit.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
```

**UPDATED**

```
                String values = "";
                Iterator<Widget> vPanelWidgets =  vp.iterator();
                while (vPanelWidgets.hasNext()){
                    Widget childWidget = vPanelWidgets.next();
                    if(childWidget instanceof ABC){
                        ABC xx = (ABC )childWidget;
                        values = String.valueOf(xx.getMagnitude());
                    }
                }
                Window.alert(values);
            }
        });

        fp.add(vp);
        return fp;
    }
```

Any insight would be appreciated.
UPDATED:
Here am comparing each of child widget component with one of my Composite component , do i have to do like this comparing to all Composite component? I there any kind of simple or optimized way to do it?
I want good solution for doing this process as there are so many composite component over there:

```
if(childWidget instanceof ABC ){
    ABC xx = (ABC )childWidget;
    values = String.valueOf(xx.getMagnitude());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make all you Composite components implement an interface having a single `getValue()` method:

```
public interface HasValue {
    public String getValue();
}
```

Then you can easilly extract the value of all widgets implementing that interface:

```
    while (vPanelWidgets.hasNext()){
        Widget childWidget = vPanelWidgets.next();
        if(childWidget instanceof HasValue){
            HasValue xx = (HasValue) childWidget;
            values = xx.getValue();
        }
    }
```

If you need to return values other than strings, you could use generics. Take a look at GWT's `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HasValue` for an example of that (you could also use that interface instead of creating your own).

Answer (score 0):

You can only add one widget in a GWT FormPanel widget and then you can get it using `getWidget()` method:

```
FormPanel panel = createFormWithComponents();

RootPanel.get().add(panel);

VerticalPanel vp = (VerticalPanel) panel.getWidget();
int widgetCount = vp.getWidgetCount();
Window.alert(widgetCount+" ...");
```

Comment: I think you didn't get what my problem actually is, I also done like that, created a Vertical Panel add it to FormPanel, and it to RootPanle.

My problem is, the components are Composite components. When submit button clicks i want to retrieve the values in that components. What i needed is the value associated with these components. Thanks.

Comment: You can put some getter method for your composite and return the required values from your composite component and get those values (using getter method) in click event handler.

Comment: How could that be so easy, main aspects of my process are:
#1. Each and every component are added dynamically
#2. Based on an XML i add composite component to a panel, then that panel to form.
#3. the vertical panel may contain another vertical panel and elements, it depends on xml.
Then how could i know which component is in the form? what type? And how can i retrieve my component from the form? Will you please provide pseudo code to retrieve components ?

Comment: Another way is you set id attribute for your widgets "fp.getElement().setAttribute("id", "fp");" and then find your widget by theirs ids "Element elem = DOM.getElementById("fb");"

Comment: Another alternative way is: if you sure that your button add to a panel and then add to FormPanel or you can find out the level of your widget from your xml files then use getParent method: "FormPanel fp = (FormPanel) (((Button) event.getSource()).getParent().getParent());"