# List all the widgets of a page/panel in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

Is there a programmatic way to read all the widget a GWT page or Panel contains?

I have several error labels in my form, all suffixed by "ErrorLabel" and I'd like to find them and clear them. I can do a list of them, but I figured out I can actually automate that if I had some...

I am using UiBinder.

Comment: Depends on what kind of `Panel` you are using. `ComplexPanel` and subclasses have the method [getChildren()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ComplexPanel.html#getChildren()) which will return an `Iterator`. You would have to implement some recursive logic as well. Don't think there is something built-in that will return all children (maybe on `Element` level?).

Comment: I'd like to avoid going to DOM or HTML level... if i Can :)

Comment: As it seems, you can even simply use an extended `for` loop on the `VerticalPanel` (because of the `Iterator`). See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7456674/1740724) for reference. This + recursion = win

Comment: Thanks @Baz . I have done it in the past, but I don't find a way to get the `ui:Field` name in the `Widget`. Maybe I'm just getting blind.

Comment: Sorry, don't use UiBinder, so I can't really help with this part.

Answer (score 1):

> Use `recursion` method to get all the children of any component.

Steps to follow: **(How to read the `UiField` names?)**

- Add below entry in you gwt.xml

  ```
  <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.Debug"/>
  ```
- Use `debugId` along with `ui:field` as shown below in your `ui.xml`

  ```
  <gwt:CheckBox ui:field="myCheckBox" debugId="myCheckBox" />
  ```
- Now you can get the Id

  ```
  myCheckBox.getElement().getId();
  ```
- All the Ids are generated with default prefix `gwt-debug-` as shown below. If you want then you can remove it.

  ```
  gwt-debug-myCheckBox
  ```

Here is a utility class:

**Note:** add more widget and component as per your requirement.

```
import java.util.Iterator;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FlexTable;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Panel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget;

public class WidgetValidator {

    private static void validateFlexTable(final FlexTable flextable) {
        for (int row = 0; row < flextable.getRowCount(); row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < flextable.getCellCount(row); column++) {
                WidgetValidator.validateWidget(flextable.getWidget(row, column));
            }
        }
    }

    private static void validatePanel(final Panel panel) {
        final Iterator<Widget> iterator = panel.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            WidgetValidator.validateWidget(iterator.next());
        }
    }

    public static void validateWidget(final Widget widget) {
        if (widget != null) {
            if (widget instanceof FlexTable) {
                WidgetValidator.validateFlexTable((FlexTable) widget);
            } else if (widget instanceof Panel) {
                WidgetValidator.validatePanel((Panel) widget);
            } else {
                System.out.println(widget.getElement().getId().replace("gwt-debug-", ""));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps as I forgot some type in my recursion. However, you still don't get the UiField name :(...

Comment: Its a initial start-up for you. Now you add new functionality in it. I have just given you a way to iterate all the children.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please have a look. If you need any sample then please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to add a class name to all the labels - for example, "errorLabel", and add the following line to your CSS file:

```
.hide .errorLabel {display: none}
```

Then, if you need to hide/show all of these labels, you can do it with a single line of code:

```
parentPanel.addStyleName("hide");
parentPanel.removeStyleName("hide");
```

Comment: I misunderstood your question. You cannot access ui:field from a Widget, other than by declaring it: `@UiField Label errorLabel`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that

```
private void myFunction(RootPanel panel) {
for (Widget w : panel) {
    if(w instanceof Label){
       //do something
    }
}
}
```