# gwtupload: Hidden values getting appended

Tags: gwt, gwt-platform, gwtupload

I'm using `SingleUploader` for uploading a file. I have few hidden fields that I'm setting on start of upload. The upload works fine but when I upload again the old hidden values do not cleared. Instead the hidden values are getting appended. `SingleUploader#clear()` seems to work for clearing the values but it also removes the *Send* `Button` from the existing form.

```
getView().getUploader().addOnStartUploadHandler(new IUploader.OnStartUploaderHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onStart(IUploader uploader) {
            if(validateForm()){
                String val1 = getView().getFirstFieldTxtBx().getValue().trim();
                String val2 = getView().getStartDateBx().getValue().toString();
                String val3 = getView().getEndDateBx().getValue().toString();

                uploader.add(new Hidden("first",val1), 0);
                uploader.add(new Hidden("second",val2),1);
                uploader.add(new Hidden("third",val3),2);
            }else{
                uploader.cancel();
            }
        }
    });
```

How do I get rid of the existing hidden values? Or is there any other way to send the hidden values to the server using **gwtupload**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `isVisible()` method to find out which components needs to be cleared. Iterate through all the children and based on there visibility clear the values.

You can use `instanceof Hidden` to find out hidden components only while iterating all the children.

Read more about [List all the widgets of a page/panel in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22864164/list-all-the-widgets-of-a-page-panel-in-gwt/22864607#22864607)

Comment: I didn't try this. But thanks. +1 for the approach. `isVisible()` isn't required here though, `instanceof Hidden` will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a workaround. I'm calling the `clearFormFields` method on finish and on cancel of upload.

```
private void clearFormFields(SingleUploader uploader) {
    removeWidget(((FlowPanel)uploader.getForm().getWidget()).getWidget(2));
    removeWidget(((FlowPanel)uploader.getForm().getWidget()).getWidget(1));
    removeWidget(((FlowPanel)uploader.getForm().getWidget()).getWidget(0));
}

private void removeWidget(Widget w) {
    if(w instanceof Hidden){
        w.removeFromParent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is a bug in the library, `uploader.clear()` should do the work, so as you dont have to do it by hand.

Feel free to open an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/issues/list) and I would take care of fixing it in the next gwtupload release.